# Gunicorn not found when demonized with supervisor to run Airbnb/Superset

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm trying to demonize Superset[https://github.com/airbnb/superset] and it use gunicorn. Im using supervisor and my config file looks like this:

```
[program:superset]
command = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/bin/superset runserver
directory = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/data/superset
environment= PATH='$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/bin/',PYTHONPATH='$PYTHONPATH:/data/superset'
autostart = false
autorestart = false
startretries = 3
stdout_logfile = /var/log/superset.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 100MB
stdout_logfile_backups = 5 
stderr_logfile = /var/log/superset_err.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 100MB
stderr_logfile_backups = 5
```

however, when I start supervisor and run the program Im getting this error in error log file 
`/bin/sh: 1: gunicorn: not found`
, but when I run the app straigth from command line it work :

```
gunicorn -w 4 --timeout 60 -b 0.0.0.0:8081 --limit-request-line 0 --limit-request-field_size 0 superset:app
```

Im running

```
gunicorn --version
gunicorn (version 19.6.0)
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: I installed superset using `pip` (i.e. `pip install superset`) and notice that it installs a python script that's a wrapper around gunicorn: `/usr/bin/superset`. Is it necessary to use `gunicorn` directly? I'm able to start superset, using `supervisord`, like this: `command=superset runserver -a 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Did you install Superset in a Python virtualenv?  That error is exactly what you would see if you didn't first switch to the virtualenv:

. ./venv/bin/activate

Answer (score 0):

I just had to explicitly call Sudo before the command, ie `command = sudo /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/bin/superset runserver -a 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

supervisor can't monitor demonized processes. Supervisor creates child processes of gunicorn and then monitors its child processes .